# Is this SELECT and ORDER BY query the most efficient way I could have done it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my journey to learn SQL, I'm writing various queries on an old database of mine, but getting into more complex things, I want to make sure I'm not over engineering this. I have a table Agent, with different agents offering different prices for cities. Multiple agents can serve the same city, each with different prices. I wanted to run a query which would return the total cost of hiring all of the agents for any given city, ordered by the most expensive.

```
WITH orderedPrices AS (
    SELECT SUM(agtFMPrice) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY agtCity) 
    AS IX FROM Agent)
SELECT IX 
FROM orderedPrices 
ORDER BY IX DESC
```

I found that doing it without the view returned by orderedPrices, it wouldn't order the prices (I assume because it's an aggregate function, or whatever they're called). Did I do this in the best way I could have, or could it be simplified?

Also, if you're feeling particularly bored, go ahead and give me a new assignment/query to do on this table. I could use the practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written in English doesn't seem to quite match qhat you have written in SQL.

English:
- One record per `City`
- One field per record, showing the total cost of all associated agents

SQL:
- One record per `Agent`
- One field per record, showing the total cost of all agents in the same city

```
 AgentID | agtCity | agtFMPrice
---------+---------+------------
    1    |    1    |     10
    2    |    1    |     20
    3    |    2    |     30
    4    |    2    |     10
    5    |    2    |     25


 Results of SQL version           Results of English version
------------------------         ----------------------------
            30                                30
            30                                65
            65
            65
            65
```

If you want the English version, I'd do this...

```
SELECT
  agtCity,
  SUM(agtFMPrice) AS IX
FROM
  Agent
GROUP BY
  agtCity
ORDER BY
  SUM(agtFMPrice) DESC
```

To assist performance, the table could (should?) also have an Index on `(agtCity)`

Comment: Whoa, that's a detailed answer, thanks, it really points out my mistake. It seems I don't quite have a grasp of SQL yet.. So it seems my partition bit is the culprit?

Comment: Also, thanks to your new query, I've learned that Null costs $14.50

Comment: `GROUP BY` aggregates groups of multiple source rows into a single row per group. You can then use `MIN/MAX/SUM/etc` to calculate the single aggregate result for those multiple rows in each group. `OVER (PARTITION BY)` allows an aggregate to be specified without acutally aggregating the rows - Applying the single aggregate result to the multiple source rows, while keeping all of the multiple source rows.

Comment: Oh, okay. For the sake of learning, how would I accomplish what you did using OVER (PARTITION BY)?

Comment: @Cost - You don't.  What I did gives one result per city from a table with many agents per city.  So, I used `GROUP BY` to aggregate groups multiple records (Each group representing one city).  `OVER (PARTITION BY)` is designed to NOT aggregate multiple records together - In your case, it ensures you still get one record per agent.

Comment: Okay, I sort of see, thanks. I'm finding SQL to be conceptually fairly different from the usual C style programming I'm used to